# Bash Script Not changing Directory

Tags: shell-script

I have a small script I am working on where I need to read in a few Strings:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter SUID: "
read $uid
echo "Enter Tag Number: "
read $dicomTag

dicomDump() {
        arg1=$1
        cd ~/export/"$1"
        dcmdump *.dcm > dcmResults.txt
}
tagFinder() {
        arg1=$1
        arg2=$2
        for i in $(cat ~/export/"$1"/dcmResults.txt); do grep "$2" | >> tagResults.txt
        break
done;
}
dicomDump "$uid"
#tagFinder "$uid" "$dicomTag"
```

First thing I notice is that in dicomDump() function, it does not change directories. When I stuck `ls` in the code it was still in the `pwd`, another thing I notice is that I am attempting to use dcmdump (which is symlinked to a program in my server with * being a wildcard). Everytime I run the script I get:

`E: dcmdump: No such file or directory: reading file: *.dcm`

Can anyone tell me why the script does not change directories as it should and how can I get it to run the dcmdump program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `read` wrong.

```
echo "Enter SUID: "
read $uid
echo "Enter Tag Number: "
read $dicomTag
```

should be

```
echo "Enter SUID: "
read uid
echo "Enter Tag Number: "
read dicomTag
```

As it is, you're calling `read` with the argument "$uid", which expands the variable "uid" to the empty string (since it hasn't been set), and then the shell drops the word from the argument list for `read` since it's empty and not quoted.  That's causing you to call the form of `read` where a variable name isn't given, and the response is stored in `$REPLY` instead.

Comment: Your da man!! I coulda sworn I've done that before and it didnt work. But either way it now works.